# Will referencing multiple columns in foreign keys affect performance in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

so I am creating a database where I have a parent table with multiple columns that I would like to have reference multiple column in a child table. I would like to create relationships between the columns in the parent table and the column in the child table. For an example, I'm passing this to SQL
parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    val1 int NOT NULL,
    val2 int NOT NULL,
    val3 int NOT NULL,
    val4 int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (val1)
);
```

child table:

```
CREATE TABLE Child (
    val1 int NOT NULL,
    val2 int,
    val3 int,
    val4 int,
    PRIMARY KEY(val1)
);
```

relationships

```
ALTER TABLE Parent ADD FOREIGN KEY (val1, Val2, Val3) REFERENCES Parent(val1, Val2, Val3).
```

Based on my above example I would like to know whether this kind of foreign key is acceptable?
Creating foreign key like this will affect query performance?

Appreciate your knowledge sharing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That foreign key won't be created, because a foreign key can only reference the columns from the primary key. and `val2` and `val3` are not part of the primary key, thus they can't be a foreign key.

Comment: Did you mean to write `alter table CHILD ..`?

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys should be used for foreign key relationships.  So, use:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    val1 int PRIMARY KEY,
    val2 int NOT NULL,
    val3 int NOT NULL,
    val4 int NOT NULL
);
```

child table:

```
CREATE TABLE Child (
    val1 int PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_val1 int,
    CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_val1) REFERENCES parent(val1)
);
```

If you want the values of the other columns, then `JOIN` them in a query.